# Scala: Write value to typesafe config object

Tags: scala, typesafe-config, hocon

I'm using Typesafe config & have a config file in my resources directory which looks like this:

```
something {
  another {
    someconfig=abc
    anotherconfig=123
  }
}
```

How would I change the value of `anotherconfig` using scala?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to change the loaded config (i.e. create a new config based on the old one), you can use withValue:

```
val newConfig = oldConfig.withValue("something.another.anotherconfig",
  ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(456))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't overwrite a value in the original Config object since it's immutable. What you can do is create a new Config object with your values, using the original as a fallback. So:

```
val myConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString("something.another.anotherconfig=456")
val newConfig = myConfig.withFallback(oldConfig)
```

and then use newConfig everywhere instead of your original Config. A more maintainable option would be to have a 2nd config file with your changes and use:

```
val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load("local")
val oldConfig = ConfigFactory.load
val realConfig = myConfig.withFallback(oldConfig)
```

You could then use a System Property to set where to load `myConfig` from.